# HQL returns duplicate entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates, hql

I have an entity like this:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "my_table")
  public class MyTable implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
     private Long recordId;

     @Column(name = "CNAME")
     private String changeName;

     @Transient
     MyTableTwo tableTwo;

     //getters and setters
 }
```

MyTableTwo entity:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "my_table_two")
  public class MyTableTwo implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "REC_ID")
     private Long recId;

     @Column(name = "CNAME")
     private String changeName;

     @Column(name = "CVAL")
     private String changeValue;

     //getters and setters
 }
```

I wrote HQL baed on `recordId`. 
HQL:

```
 SELECT mt from MyTable where recordId = 123
```

Matches 4 records with the ID 123. But these rows are unique.

`recordId` has duplicate values in the database. So I am assuming, if there are 4 entities that have same `recordId` say `123`. then the first entity will be repeated 4 times.

**Q1. Is this correct? (Currently, I am getting the results like this, duplicate rows. So I wanted to confirm, duplicate `recordId` is causing this issue.**

Now I need to join `MyTableTwo` on a field name.

In a regular query I would write like this:

```
select my_table.record_id, my_table_two.rec_id, my_table_two.change_val 
  FROM my_table, my_table_tow
 where my_table.cname = my_table_two.cname;
```

**Q2. How to do with the above entity setup?**

**Q3: Does it solve the duplicate entity problem? (Join with the other table)**

Comment: Can you post the HQL query?

Comment: @Kevin Rave Well in Hibernate a column marked with @@Id indicates that this is the primary key. So don't annotate the recId property with @@Id. Create compound key using hibernate or create a column which is an auto-number (Row Id)

Comment: @Khush, I understand that concept well. I would like to know two things: 1.) How to map with the `@transient` entity, and 2.) if the duplicate is solved by mapping?

Comment: @KevinRave What I understand from transient entity is that the entity does not exist as a table in the database?

Comment: It is a table (so Entity). `my_table_two`. The 2nd entity class.

Comment: @KevinRave I would be very interested to know how you solve this issue. Please keep me posted.